# JSP Form page goes into infinite loop when action URL is initialized from a variable

Tags: java, jsp, struts, validation

I have a simple JSP as follows:

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" 
      action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/validateLoginID.do" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name = "loginID" id="loginID" value="${loginID}"/>
</form> 

<script> 

window.alert("Submitting form!");
document.myform.submit();
</script>
```

The above JSP code works. But when I try to initialize the action from a variable instead, using something like:

```
action="${myLink}" method="POST">
```

It goes into an infinite loop, printing "Submitting form!" each time. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably because the action it submits the form to returns the above page, which submits the form, which displays the page, which submits the form, etc.

Comment: Of course that's the first thing I checked, but myLink contains the same link that the action contained earlier.

Comment: Well, then the code of the action must have changed. Use a debugger and step throught the action code to see what it does. Putting a button in the form and submitting it manually would help in inspecting the contents of the page before the form is submitted again.

Answer (score 0):

`"myLink"` was actually a dummy name for the variable "name" that I was actually using. I tried to mimic `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` and have a name like that, but unfortunately, the **dot** in the variable name was causing the problem. With the dot removed, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think the struts validation framework implied underneath the code above. A far as it returns the input the same page involve the javascript to submit the page with errors again and it's repeating.  Remove `document.myform.submit();` or make function

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function doSubmit(){
  window.alert("Submitting form!");
  document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
```

that will stop submitting on load.